# Override M2_HOME in console doesn't work

Tags: maven, path, console

I have a problem with the Maven M2_HOME environment variable.

Everytime I override the variable in console it says:

```
M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Maven installation
```

Here is my configuration.

I've two maven installations, one for version 3.3.9 and one for version 3.2.5.
I need version 3.2.5 in a while.

So I created two additional environment variables M2_HOME_3_3_9 and M2_HOME_3_2_5 and the M2_HOME variable of course which is part of the `PATH` like `%M2_HOME%\bin`.

By default M2_HOME is set to %M2_HOME_3_3_9%.

If I need maven 3.2.5 I open the console and send the following command:

```
SET M2_HOME=%M2_HOME_3_2_5%
```

After that maven give me the error above.

If I start the console with M2_HOME changed to %M2_HOME_3_2_5% in the environment settings everything works fine.

With regards.

Comment: when you execute `set M2_HOME` in your console, what is the output?

Comment: Before change via set 
M2_HOME=PATH TO 3.3.9
M2_HOME_3_2_5= PATH TO 3.2.5
M2_HOME_3_3_9 = PATH TO 3.3.9
So this works.

After SET
M2_HOME=PATH TO 3.2.5
M2_HOME_3_2_5= PATH TO 3.2.5
M2_HOME_3_3_9 = PATH TO 3.3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also modify the `PATH` environment variable after you change `M2_HOME`?

In other words: what is the content of your `PATH` environment variable?

I guess you'll get problems if the executable maven file is located in `%M2_HOME_3_2_5%/bin` while `M2_HOME` points to `%M2_HOME_3_3_9%`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've added the M2_HOME variable to the PATH like `%M2_HOME%\bin`. So when M2_HOME is changed the PATH is also changed. I've added this part to my question. This works with JAVA_HOME as well.

Comment: Okay. Thats weird. I've checked your question.
My Path is set as I mentioned BUT when I change the `M2_HOME` variable  the `PATH` isn't changed. And then I have what you say `M2_HOME` points to 3.2.5 but the `PATH` points to 3.3.9.

Which is the same with `JAVA_HOME`. My mistake was that I've checked the change of `JAVA_HOME`
 via `mvn -version` and not via `java -version`.

Comment: @Maxx I don't understand how JAVA_HOME is concerned ... do you have multiple Java versions installed and want to change the used one like you want to do with maven???

Comment: My Question is answered I've found my mistake. I use two JAVA installations, one for java8 and one for java6, thats why I also need two maven installations. But maven reads the `JAVA_HOME` variable, that's why when I change `JAVA_HOME` like `SET JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME6%` and execute `mvn -version` the java version 1.6 is displayed. I've tough that the PATH is changed now and was confused why this doesn't work with maven. But like you said, the `PATH` isn't changed just the variable. I also did some research that it's not possible to change the PATH that easily. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The only things you need to is to add (set) the bin folder of the maven distribution you would like to use in your PATH nothing more. No need to use `M2_HOME` etc.

Furthermore the repository is by default at `$HOME/.m2/repository` and you shouldn't change that and definitively not to the maven installation. Do not do this. The settings.xml you should change is only your own file which is located in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`. You should prevent to change the files in the distribution....

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've added the M2_HOME variable to my PATH like  `%M2_HOME%\bin` so if I change M2_HOME the PATH is changed. Which works JAVA_HOME. I've edited my question and add the part with the PATH.

Comment: For Java Home for Maven it's better to use `$HOME/.mavenrc` or for Windows `$HOME/mavenrc_pre.bat` or `$HOME/mavenrc_pre.cmd` where you can set JAVA_HOME. Furthermore you should not use `M2_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

sudo nano /etc/profile

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_73
export JAVA_HOME

M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.0
export M2_HOME

M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export M2

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$M2
export PATH
```

Change the path to which ever java and maven you are using add the above lines at the end of this file.
Then restart your PC and check the following in a terminal:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME 
echo $M2_HOME
echo $M2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export %M2_HOME_3_2_5%=$HOME_3_2_5/builds/maven
export M2_HOME=%M2_HOME_3_2_5%
export M2_REPO=$M2_HOME/repository
```

In $M2_HOME/conf create a settings.xml file with this content:

```
<settings>
<localRepository>${env.M2_HOME}/repository</localRepository>
</settings>
```

Comment: why do recommend to locate the maven repository within the maven installation folder? That's wrong. The same local repository can be used for all maven versions > 2

Comment: and it's wrong to modify the `settings.xml` within M2_HOME